# Cannot send a file with curl to another server

Tags: php, curl, cross-platform

The scenario is to send a file from a PHP application in server1 to a C#.net application in server2, but:

- While sending a file using a simple HTML form, the destination server receives it with no problem
- While sending the file using cURL and receiving it by server1 using PHP, file is received with no problem.
- While sending that file using cURL I get error 500 from destination server

Note that I don't have access to the destination server and its admin is sure that everything is okay because of the the successful submission of HTML form.

```
<?php
$filedata = $fileName;
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); 
$postfields = array("filedata" => "@$filedata", "filename" => $fileName);
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://server1/newspanel/index.php/jnews/get', //200
    //CURLOPT_URL => 'http://server2/postphoto.aspx', //500
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize($filedata),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
```

What is worng with my code that only me can receive the file?

Comment: @kohjah it looks fine to me too, but I still get error 500 when I send a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that .net is sensitive to header parameters of request and PHP is not!
You have to mention all the parameters by cURL just like a browser sending request to the server.
Sending parameters like `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept-Language`, `Cache-Control`, `Connection`, `User-Agent` and etc. seems to be fixing the problem.